# How do I load and store global variables in Jersey/Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I am creating a RESTful Web Service that wraps an antiquated vendor API.  Some external configuration will be required and will be stored on the server either in a file or rdbms.  I'm using Jersey 1.11.1 in Glassfish 3.1.2.  This configuration data is all in String key/value format.

My first question is this - where can I store global/instance variables in Jersey so that they will be persisted between requests and available to all resources?  If this was a pure Servlet application I would use the ServletContext to accomplish this.

The second part to the question is how can I load my configuration once the Jersey server has loaded?  Again, my Servlet analogy would be to find the equivalent to the init() method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@Singleton @Startup` EJB matches your requirements.

```
@Singleton
@Startup // initialize at deployment time instead of first invocation
public class VendorConfiguration {

    @PostConstruct
    void loadConfiguration() {
        // do the startup initialization here
    }

    @Lock(LockType.READ) // To allow multiple threads to invoke this method
                         // simultaneusly
    public String getValue(String key) {
    }
}


@Path('/resource')
@Stateless
public class TheResource {
    @EJB
    VendorConfiguration configuration;
    // ...
}
```

*EDIT:* Added annotation as per Graham's comment

Comment: This looks like a great solution and it runs properly at load time, but I get an InvocationTargetException (displayed as NullPointerException by the container) when I try to reference this EJB in my Resource classes.

Comment: From the Jersey mailing list:  _By default injection of EE resources are not supported unless you turn the resource into a managed bean (and note that there are some constraints when turning a resource class into a managed bean)._

Comment: Once I added a @Stateless flag to my resources this worked perfectly and is definitely a great solution.  These two pages helped me understand the concepts a little better, too: [EJB 3.1 AND REST - THE LIGHTWEIGHT HYBRID](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_and_rest)     [Singletons](https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/singletons)

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [listener](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) for init the variables and set to the context as attribute before the web application start, something like the following:

```
package org.paulvargas.shared;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class LoadConfigurationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // read file or rdbms
        ...
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        // set attributes
        ...
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        // remove attributes
        ...
    }

}
```

This listener is configured in the `web.xml`.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.paulvargas.shared.LoadConfigurationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can use the `@Context` annotation for inject the `ServletContext` and retrieving the attribute.

```
package org.paulvargas.example.helloworld;

import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("/world")
public class HelloWorld {

    @Context
    private ServletContext context;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
    public String getGreeting() {

        // get attributes
        String someVar = (String) context.getAttribute("someName")

        return someVar + " says hello!";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is definitely a workable solution, but it involves adding a web.xml where I currently have none and also some extra work in order to filter out the other attributes that exist in the ServletContext.  I gave this an upvote, but had to award the answer to the other post as it is both simpler and more versatile.