# How many Mongo instances to launch in a client / server app?

Tags: mongodb, glassfish, client-server

Context:
A client sends calls to a server to execute a job. For each job, I create a new MongoClient (with Morphia):

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("000.00.000.000", 27017);
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
Datastore ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "myDatastore");
//operations on the datastore: save, find, update...
```

The question: is it good practice / totally wrong? Or should I create only one MongoClient / Morphia instance for the whole app as a global variable, and let it be called by each job? ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503599/how-do-i-load-and-store-global-variables-in-jersey-glassfish))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc for the Mongo Java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/#java-driver-concurrency) says:

> The Java MongoDB driver is thread safe. If you are using in a web
>   serving environment, for example, you should create a single
>   MongoClient instance, and you can use it in every request. The
>   MongoClient object maintains an internal pool of connections to the
>   database (default pool size of 10). For every request to the DB (find,
>   insert, etc) the Java thread will obtain a connection from the pool,
>   execute the operation, and release the connection. This means the
>   connection (socket) used may be different each time.

So... one MongoClient per app, not per job called.